# How to configure VS to automatically generate custom code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For example, I have an enum structure written in c# as below:

```
enum foobar:int
{
    foo,
    bar
}
```

Now I want to automatically generate a class for each enum item with the same name(eg `foo`-->`class foo`,`bar`-->`class bar`).
 Is there a language level solution(eg using `codedom`) or an IDE level solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use T4 for your purpose https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: I am using vs2017. Is the Visual Studio SDK a necessity in order to use T4?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bac4e0df-7b82-4f44-8bb5-39e99bf02a9a/can-i-run-t4-templates-on-build-without-vs-sdk-and-modeling-sdk?forum=dslvsarchx